# Recent files in folder

Tags: linux, unix, file, find, logging

I want to check files which are recently added to the folder in unix environment.

is there any find check

```
     find -name 'filename' timestamp last 5 mins ??
```

Comment: I think you must get all the files and then filter on their create datetime.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To locate files modified less than 5 minutes ago

```
find -name 'filename'  -mmin -5
```

From the man page:

```
   -mmin n
          File's data was last modified n minutes ago.

   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.
```

-mmin is supported under most recent versions of GNU find.

Comment: Note the minus sign in `-mmin -5` for "less than five minutes ago"

Comment: `-mmin 5` means "exactly five minutes ago"

Answer (score 11):

To find all files modified in the last 24 hours (last full day) in current directory and its sub-directories:

```
find . -mtime -1 -print
```

[Source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/01/19/find-files-that-are-modified-today-or-since-certain-time-ago-in-unix/)

Answer (score 1):

In [zsh](http://www.zsh.org):

```
ls *(mm-5)   # or 'mh' to detect stuff modified in the last 5 hours etc.
```